# Refinery: trying to associate a controller action with a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I have a refinery app, and I have a view in...

```
vendor/extensions/refinerycms-calendar/app/views/refinery/calendar/events/test.html.erb
```

...then in my controller in...

```
vendor/extensions/refinerycms-calendar/app/controllers/refinery/calendar/events_controller.rb
```

I have defined a correstponing action with a simple...

```
def test

end
```

When I go to /class-schedule/test I get the error

```
ArgumentError in Refinery::Calendar::EventsController#index
```

So my question is what route do I need to add to config/routes to get this page to use my 'test' action? Here are a few I'm tried...

```
get 'test', to: 'Refinery::Calendar::EventsController#test', as: 'test'

get 'test', to: 'events#test', as: 'test'
```

Comment: we need more parts of your routes.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

It was definetely an issue with routes. I ending up solving the issue with this route...

```
  get 'class-schedule/test', to: 'Refinery::Calendar::events#test', as: 'test'
```

...and just to flesh out my controller action I'm doing...

```
  def test
    @events = Refinery::Calendar::Event.all
  end
```

...and in my view I can do things like...

```
<%= e.title  %>
  <p>
<% end %>
```

Hope this can help someone else out!